# Source not found when debugging on server (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I'm developing a web service, and whenever I try to debug on server this is what I get, even though if I run on server everything goes fine!!!
I've been stuck on this now for 2 days !!!

Thanks for the help guys.

[image: Screenshot of Source Not Found]

**UPDATE**
clicking on change attached source shows:
[image: Attach source screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 3 days stuck on this, all I had to do is to Remove all break points by going to

```
breakpoints view -> Right click on any breakpoint -> remove all
```

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse debugger needs the source code of what's executing on the server.  Typically, you can download the source online as a jar or zip, then save it somewhere on your machine. Then click "Change Attached Source" and point to the downloaded source jar or directory where the zip was extracted.
~NCM